# Using a view specific connection string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, database-connection, connection-string

I upgraded an old website from ASP.NET to MVC recently and now I am running into a user login problem with one of my views. In the old situation I would have a separate `web.config` in the folder for that page that would set the connection string specifically for that page. Now I would like to do that in ASP.NET MVC as well, however the `web.config` in the specific views folder does not work. I also tried to change the `web.config` in the views folder, but maybe I did this in a wrong way because it did not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish the same result in ASP.NET MVC as I had in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a separate configuration file, as explained in this MSDN article?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Comment: Thank you for your reply it helped, but this was not the only thing i had to do. I already had a separate file for my connection strings. Due to how the solution is setup i could detect in my datamanager from which page i am making the call to the database. From that I can select a different connection string in my datamanager.

I had hoped to do it in the same way as in my old website but that probably is not possible.